# Cucumber - Java - Non-ASCII characters in an identifier

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, non-ascii-characters

Hi community: I'm working with Cucumber in another language different than English.

When I generate the Step Definitions it displays a message over the void method

```
Non-ASCII characters in an identifier
```

This is the Step Definition sample.

```
@Y("^se despliega un menú lateral con diferentes opciones$")
   public void seDespliegaUnMenúLateralConDiferentesOpciones() {}
```

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed an Intellij IDEA "code inspection" setting.

I found the setting here:

```
File (Menu) 
  > Settings
     > In left pane of the popup window, open "Editor"
        > Choose "Inspections" 
           > Type "ASCII" into the "search" text field
              > Select "Non-ASCII characters" under "Internationalization"
```

The popup window then looks as below, and you can unmark the option on the bottom right.

[image: Inspection options as shown by IDEA]

Answer (score 7):

This is an inspection generated by IDEA (presumably). It intends to guard against possible complications related to character encoding. However as you are using Cucumber in a language other then English you will be dealing with these anyway. This makes the warning superfluous.

You can turn the warning off by selecting the method name, pressing Alt-Enter and from the menu search for the "Edit Inspection Profile Option".

Comment: Thanks a lot M.P. Korstanje